# why is count always 0 for result set?

Tags: php, sql-server

I'm trying to do a distinct count inside my query and return the field, but it continues to return 0.

```
// Get the total 
$query = "select count (distinct field_name) from table_name";

$rs = $conn->execute($query);

$count = $rs->Fields(0)->value;

echo $count;
```

Can I not call field on a count value?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://phplens.com/lens/adodb/docs-adodb.htm#fields

```
$query = "select count (distinct field_name) as cnt from table_name";
...
$count = $rs->Fields[0];

or 
$count = $rs->Fields("cnt");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use mysql_num_rows to get the exact records returned in resultset

Comment: I should have mentioned this is mssql and I'm connecting via ADO

Comment: it's `sql-server` not `MySQL`

Comment: Even in MySQL, this answer would have yield `1`, always.